# Is it possile to cast two different class but having the same attributes?

Tags: java

I have two classes. ClassA and CLassB, they don't have any relation but they both have the same attributes. Is it possible to cast them or I have to set the attributes one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to "cast" them universally is using the reflection like this:

```
public static void copyObject(Object src, Object dest)
        throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
        NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
    for (Field field : src.getClass().getFields()) {
        dest.getClass().getField(field.getName()).set(dest, field.get(src));
    }
}
```

Example:

```
static class ClassA {
    public int a;
    public String b;
    public double c;
}

static class ClassB {
    public int a;
    public String b;
    public double c;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ClassA a = new ClassA();
    a.a = 1;
    a.b = "test";
    a.c = 3.14;

    ClassB b = new ClassB();
    copyObject(a, b);
    System.out.println(b.a+", "+b.b+", "+b.c); // prints "1, test, 3.14"
}
```

However, as you may guess, that's not very good way to do things in Java.

Comment: Note that this is not recursive.

Answer (score 4):

Use Json serialization/deserialization, e.g. with Gson,

```java
    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    
    static Gson gson = new Gson();

    Class2 transform (final Class1 original) {
        return gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(original), Class2.class);
    }
```

This also works recursively.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an `Interface` that gets implemented by both classes to set the attributes.

That way instead of casting you reference them by the interface

Example

```
public interface PersonalInfo {

    public void setName(String name);
    public void setAge(int age);

}
```

Then your implementations

```
public class ClassA implements PersonalInfo {


String name;
int age;

//other things and methods
@Override
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

}
```

And for ClassB

```
public class ClassB implements PersonalInfo {

String name;
int age;

//other things and methods

@Override
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure he wants an interface. He mentions that they don't have any relation.

Comment: There is no relationship between objects which implement the same interface. Both are independent implementations of their own. They just follow the protocol defined by the interface.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't cast instances from one class to another class if they don't have any kind of relation. Take a look at the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html) for possible casts and conversions.

You can however copy attributes either by hand or using a framework such as [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

The class can't be cast'd if it doesn't have "is a" relationship (Inheritance). In this scenario, it must be set the attributes one by one. May be adding a method to one of the class to do transform.

```
public class ClassB {
    private int num;

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }
    public ClassA transformToClassA(){
        ClassA obj= new ClassA();
        obj.setNum(this.num);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't cast them. You could either manually set attributes (preferable way) or write some sort of processor that will read class definition and set fields from the fields with the same names - but that would be very fragile, because if, say you'll decide to change the type of some attribute and types of this attribute in class A would become incompatible with attribute in class B, you'll spot this only at run-time. The same would happen if you later decide to add attribute to one of them, but not the other. You could obviously devise some defense against that, but that would mean creating a complex logic, while you can simply manually set attributes without any logic whatsoever and get compile-time check.